# How can I retrieve Google Chrome bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks

Here is what happened:  At first, I upgraded Mozilla Firefox browser to it's latest version.

Then, I realized that all my bookmarks in Google Chrome were gone.

In my panic, I imported the bookmarks of Firefox to Google Chrome just in case they were transferred, but they weren't.

Then, I searched over my computer to find the bookmarks location of Chrome and I found the two relevant files

- Bookmarks
- Bookmarks.bak

but they were updated too. What else can I do to restore my bookmarks?

Comment: Are you using windows XP, 7 or 8? Do you have a Windows system backup from an earlier state? You can open these backups and look for old bookmark files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if the bookmarks have been overwritten, there is no way to restore them. You can try to use an SQLite browser such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ to open the Bookmarks file and try to salvage as much information as possible.

If you use Chrome's sync functionality, leave your current browser session open, then go to another computer and log in to your Chrome sync account to access and export your bookmarks. You can see if your bookmarks are still stored by Google by looking at https://www.google.com/dashboard/b/0/

Good luck!